# how to boot OSX by default and boot Ubuntu from USB? Bypass Grub2

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, mac, boot-order

I am new to Linux so this may be a stupid question but I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find an answer.

I have made a live-USB with Ubuntu on, to use with my Mac. I don't want it installed on my Mac (yet!), but would like to be able to use it as and when I plug the USB drive in. I have installed the operating system on the USB itself in the hope to do so.

Currently, when I boot my Mac it immediately displays "GNU Grub2", however I was wondering if there is a way to boot into OSX by default bypassing this?

If I hold the 'options' key when I power on, it takes me to a screen where I can select Macintosh HD and boot into OSX. But is there a way to set it that:

"GNU Grub2" does not appear/load when power button is pressed,

OSX boots up by default unless the 'options' key is held,

and when the 'options' key is held, a choice of Macintosh HD or the USB drive is given?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if Macs can change boot priority. Can't you just unplug the USB drive?

Comment: When the USB drive is unplugged it still goes to the Grub screen, but I was hoping that when it is unplugged it will boot straight to OSX?

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood. I think you need to look up how to remove GRUB from the Mac.

Comment: If I removed Grub, would this allow me to boot from the USB, as currently when I hold the options key on startup, it only displays "Macintosh HD"?

Comment: I think you will have to try to install GRUB to the USB. I'm not sure how, but I'd look at one of the guides for installing to USB, which should tell you how to avoid installing GRUB to HDD.